# How can I convert bitcoin to any other new launched coins?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

I have a bitcoin wallet and need to convert all user wallet balance into new launched coin.

Comment: Please be more clear as your question doesn't seem to have any sense.

For converting funds to other coins send funds to an Exchange and trade them there. If you are referring to claiming forked coins with your current private keys, rephrase your question so someone can help you if possible.

Comment: I have a MLM website which accepting payment in bitcoin. but I want to start accepting payment in KLEYN coin. and I want to convert all member's wallet balance bitcoin to  KLEYN coin.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a bitcoin wallet and need to convert all user wallet balance into new launched coin.

Well, if you want to convert your Bitcoin balance in your wallet to a newly launched coin, you can do the following:

1. Find a compatible wallet for the currency you want to get. Then, register a wallet on there.
2. Find a trusted exchange for Bitcoin to altcoin, some are:

https://.kucoin.com/altcoin/exchange

https://www.binance.com/

3. Create a account onto the exchange, and finally, exchange your Bitcoin to a Altcoin.

**I hope this helped!**